# Redirect from old domain to new page on new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble with some redirects. We've moved a site off an old domain to a new subfolder on a new domain, and we've shuffled some of the pages around. So I'm trying to, for example, move `old-domain.com/about/` to `new-domain.com/subfolder/about/` or `old-domain-com/convoluted-autogenerated-page-slug/` to `new-domain/subfolder/page/` (i.e. not a match on the file name at all times).

The basic code I've used in my `.htaccess` file here is something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/subfolder/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com/about/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/subfolder/about/ [L,R=301]
```

`old-domain.com/` redirects to `new-domain.com/subfolder/` but `old-domain.com/about/` is also just redirecting to `new-domain.com/subfolder/`, not the specific page I want. I can't seem to get a pretty literal list of old URLs to redirect to specific new URLs. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Well I am afraid we can't be of help with finding a list of pages and where to redirect them too...

Comment: Tried to clarify a bit with an edit. Though I might not understand how to redirect a list of pages to a different list of pages on a new domain, so again, guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your only problem is that you use the wrong order of rules: you need to specify the specific rules _first_, then more general rules later on, so further down, since a list of rules is processed from top to bottom. `/about` is more specific than just `/` for example.